# How to add Windows 10 to grub boot loader?

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot, grub, mbr

1. I have installed Windows 10
2. I have installed Linux Mint Silvia and I have chosen a device for boot loader installation - sda.
3. There is not Windows 10 in grub menu when the system starts
4. I have booted via Linux Mint live USB.
5. I Do step by step https://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd
6. But it still no Windows 10 in grub menu
7. I have booted via live windows 10 USB.
8. With restoration tools, I have chosen the command line
9. I have fixed Mbr by console command bootrec /FixMbr
10. Ok, windows 10 is loading by there is no Grub.
11. I have repeated steps 4 and 5
12. There is no result

Also, I have tried to change grub config with this answer
https://askubuntu.com/questions/661947/add-windows-10-to-grub-os-list#answer-977251 - But in this case, There is Windows 10 - but when I chose - I will recursively going to grub

And with this answer
https://askubuntu.com/questions/661947/add-windows-10-to-grub-os-list#answer-890562
I have an error message when chose Windows 10 - There is no bootmgr directory

Thanks @Kinnectus for help

Also, I have tried

```
sudo os-prober
```

And getting

```
/dev/sda1:FreeDOS:FreeDOS:chain
/dev/sda2:FreeDOS:FreeDOS1:chain
```

And then I have tried

```
sudo update-grub
```

And getting

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-38-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-38-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found FreeDOS on /dev/sda1
Found FreeDOS on /dev/sda2
done
```

Unfortunately - there is not Windows 10 in grub menu

Also, I have fdisk output.

```
Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1            2048  16779263  16777216     8G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sda2  *     16779264  33556479  16777216     8G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sda3        33556480 770219115 736662636 351,3G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       770220030 976771071 206551042  98,5G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       770220032 976771071 206551040  98,5G 83 Linux

Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

There is an issue. 
Maybe the problem is with this issue?

Please, help me, I am stucking with this a whole day.
I completely have no idea, what am I doing wrong.

Comment: First of all they are on different hdd/ssd, if not check windows hdd/ssd if there a vfat partion . if you not found any the best solution it reinstall  windows, it's brutal but the easy way

Answer (score 40):

1. Boot to your Linux
2. Open a Terminal window
3. Type: `sudo os-prober`
4. If the results identify a Windows 10 install, type `sudo update-grub` which will update the GRUB entries and add it
5. Reboot your computer and test to see if Windows 10 is a new option to select.
6. End of instruction.

Comment: os-prober IDs another OS, but not Windows, but the partition is there, undisturbed. What can I do to boot Windows?  I beleve the problem is that Windows is hibernated, but if I can't login, how do I unhibernate it?

Comment: `os-prober` worked great but grub menu was not showing. It took this: `GRUB_TERMINAL=console` and `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu` in `/etc/default/grub`. As always, don't forget `sudo update-grub`. Ubuntu 20.04.2 with MATE desktop (https://askubuntu.com/a/1230221/652884)

Comment: awesome! actually what you need after restoring acronis image of ubuntu partitions)

Answer (score -1):

Try **[Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)** tool. It seems easy and working in most cases

See details in answer https://askubuntu.com/a/661954/728585

Comment: Why, how might it help without needing to click the link to see it for the part you got working?

Comment: This worked for me and solved several problems I didn't know I had.
Allowed me to boot at least from Ubuntu, however, didn't solve the 'add windows to grub' part.