# No direct Windows boot loader after Ubuntu installation alongside Windows 10 on HP Envy x360 UEFI Firmware

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, multi-boot, bootloader, grub2

This might be a question with a lot of details required and I would try to provide all of them.

I recently bought a new laptop HP Envy x360 15.6" Touchscreen 2-in-1 Laptop - AMD Ryzen 5 4500U - 1080p Model number: 15-ds1063cl. I installed ubuntu alongside Windows 10 which it already had with BIOS mode as UEFI. 1.)After installation the grub bootloader has the following entries:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vs0gX.png)

Please ignore the last entry as that is manually created by me by adding this via gedit(part of troubleshooting activity). That entry also points to recovery. enter image description here

2.) The Windows Boot Manager option(Third entry) takes me to the recovery and the only way I can load Windows 10 is by entering UEFI Firmware settings -> pressing F9 -> selecting the Windows option from Boot Menu(Refer screenshots below): enter image description here enter image description here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQU6T.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpmRC.jpg)

What I want is the windows 10 boot option to be available as grub entry and I should not be made to enter UEFI Firmware settings as that takes some time to load and it is a cumbersome process. Much like other normal installations, the windows entry should be available in the main list. Only due to this issue I may have to unistall ubuntu which I don't want to. Can anyone help me with this?

Note: Please pardon me for the unprofessional screenshots. I didn't want to invest a lot of time for a simple question

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal, type:

sudo os-prober

if Windows shows up in the list, then just:

sudo update-grub.

If that doesn't work, more options discussed here:

[How to add Windows 10 to grub boot loader?](https://superuser.com/questions/1392316/how-to-add-windows-10-to-grub-boot-loader)

Comment: I ran the command and it adds bootmfgw.efi. That boot loader is the one which is landing me into recovery. As I stated in my question the windows 10 boot loader comes in after I enter UEFI Fiorware settings.
Please read the exact details in my questions about what I am trying to get information about